# Is it feasible that Several UARTs use the same DMA buffer?

Tags: c, embedded

five UARTs are used in my project,they all enable the DMA-RX channel and UART-IdleLine Interrupt to receive data of random lengths.

In UART-RX interrupt,the data will copy from DMA buffer to the ring buffer of the specific UARTs.

For every UART,I have to declare a DMA buffer and a ring buffer which may larger than DMA buffer.And Some UARTs like a PPP-UART have large data to receive,but the SRAM of my chip is limited and the interrupt is not allowed to nest.So I wonder is it possible that all UARTs use one DMA buffer.

After testing this,it seems to work well 5 UARTs using the same DMA buffer.Anything that I should pay attention to?

Comment: It would be helpful with information about platform, OS (if any) and so on.

Comment: @unwind  *"SRAM of my chip is limited and the interrupt is not allowed to nest"*  OS?

Comment: (a) I suppose you mean that data will be copied *to* the DMA buffer for UART-RX. (b) This only has a chance to work if you can guarantee that only one UART will be active at a time for the entire duration of each data package.

Comment: @0___________ Yeah ... sounds bare-metal, but why not be obvious and say that, then?

Comment: Using DMA and ring buffers at the same time sounds counter-intuitive. The whole purpose of using DMA is to get rid of ring buffers.

Comment: I'm using FreeRTOS on Cortex-M4

Comment: @Lundin ,But I have to call UART_ReceiveEDMA at the end of the UART interrupt,if not an UART overrun may generate at the next time.Do you have any good idea?

Comment: Simply don't use UART rx interrupts if you are using DMA to do the job instead?

Comment: @Lundin no, it is to get rid of the core. Imagine 10M UART reception in interrupts :). 1M interrupts per second, lets say 50-70 clocks to very efficiently handle it (ARM needs ~20 to enter exit the handler). 70MHz micro will be barely able to handle single UART interrupts.

Comment: @0___________ That's kind of what I just said in the latest comment above?

Comment: @Lundin *"The whole purpose of using DMA is to get rid of ring buffers"* and it is not correct

Comment: @0___________ "Simply don't use UART rx interrupts if you are using DMA to do the job instead?" And the main reason you'd use ring buffers would be because you are using rx interrupts. Sure you can grab stuff out of the raw DMA buffer and put it in a ring buffer, but that sounds like a strange program design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can't. DMA receive is happening without the core knowledge. If more than one UART will receive data the data will be corrupted. The interrupts only inform you if the DMA controller has reached the end (or middle) of the buffer or if UART receiver (if capable) is idle for a particular time.